# How to "dual" join in a SQL query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite query like this:

```
SELECT Books.title, People.name FROM Books, People WHERE People.ID=Books.AuthorID
```

Where `Books.AuthorID` is an ID number corresponding to an ID in the People table.

Output:

```
Title   Author
Book1   John Doe
Book2   Martha James
```

But I want to add in a 3rd field (Books.EditorID) that also is an ID which has to be looked up in `People`, but chances are it'll be a different ID/Person than `Books.AuthorID` is.

Desired output:

```
Title   Author        Editor
Book1   John Doe      Jack Brown
Book2   Martha James  Bob Nelson
```

How can this be accomplished? I believe some sort of JOIN query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT b.title, a.name as author_name, e.name as editor_name
FROM Books b
INNER JOIN People a ON a.ID=b.AuthorID
INNER JOIN People e on e.ID=b.EditorID
```

Comment: I'm not sure `a.ID=a.AuthorID` makes sense to me? That's suppose to be `People.ID=People.AuthorID`? People only has `ID`, it's Books that has multiple IDs.

Comment: good point, AuthorID and EditorID are both supposed to be from b.  I will correct.

Comment: Also the end result is suppose to print off the book title, and 2 different peoples name. Your select seems to only pick one name?

Comment: Sorry, I copied your sample SQL for the solution... I will correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just join back to the same table with an alias...
Example coming soon.

```
SELECT 
    Book.Title,
        People.Name,
        People2.name
    FROM
        Books
    INNER JOIN
        People
    ON
        People.ID = Books.AuthorID
    INNER JOIN
        People People2
    ON
        People2.ID = People.ID
```

Comment: Hmm, but `People` only has 1 ID; there's no `EditorID`. Books is what has multiple IDs pointing to People.

Comment: JBurace just change to meet your needs `People2.ID = People.ID`